# Why is logger level always zero? And how can I get the real level?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Does anyone know why is logger level in all these codes returning zero? I have tested in the latest Anaconda (as of Feb 2020) and a source compiled python 3.6. Using Spyder, Pycharm, and command line. It always returns 0. I take it I'm doing something wrong. Also, how can I get the actual level? Critical:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.CRITICAL)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Error:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Warning:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.WARNING)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Info

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Debug:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Notset:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.NOTSET)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Even if I pass an integer as the level. 50:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=50)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

40:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=40)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

30:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=30)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

20:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=20)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

10:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=10)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

0:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=0)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.level)
```

Comment: [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) only impacts the root logger, and `logging.getLogger` gives you other loggers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What is the correct way of setting the level then? How can I get the root logger?

Comment: Why does it matter what level those other loggers are at? Surely you only care about what *output* you get, which comes out of the handler attached to the root logger (which you can access by calling `getLogger` without a name).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I think I found a solution. The reason I need the root is that I have two kinds of logs. If the user runs the app in debug mode, there has to be an extensive log. If it is ran in normal mode, there is minimum log. So I should know which level of log the user has initiated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I found my solution. Thanks! If you post your comments as an answer I'll select it as the correct answer. Thanks again.